# How to conditionally display client-side data with Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

Is there a way in Aurelia to say 'If x == **this**, then show **this**'?

```
To be specific, I have an array of data that looks something like this:
[
     {objectID: 1, customDataArray: [1,2,3,4], customDataType: { cdt: "Troops" }}
]
```

This array obviously has multiple rows that look like the one above where it's passing me an array of custom values that I need to reference. Those values could be the IDs of different 'groups' in our system. That's why we are passing in an object the contains what *type* of custom data it is. e.g. "Troops"

So what's happening is on Activate, I'm fetching all this data from my API and storing it in a variable. Well based on whether the custom data type is "Troops" or something else, I want to show a different input label. For example, if it is "Troops," I want to show a label that says "input troop id's" and so on.

**Also**, sometimes the customDataType isn't required so it comes in as null. So in that case, I want to show something different. Not sure how to handle this one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if` custom attribute or the `show` custom attribute would work. Unfortunately, we don't have a `switch` or `else` type of setup.

```
<label if.bind="p.customDataType.cdt === 'Troops'">Input Troop Ids</label>
<label if.bind="p.customDataType.cdt !== 'Troops'">Something Different</label>
```

Comment: Perfect. Didn't know you could get that deep with the if.bind binding! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could try if `if.bind` could be useful for this, as below:

```
  <ul>
    <li repeat.for="obj of data"  if.bind="obj.customDataType">
      <span>${obj.customDataType.cdt}</span> - 
      <strong repeat.for="cda of obj.customDataArray">${cda}, </strong>
    </li>
    <li repeat.for="obj of data"  if.bind="!obj.customDataType">
      <span>No CustomDataType</span>
      <strong repeat.for="cda of obj.customDataArray">${cda}, </strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Here is a plunker that shows this in action: https://gist.run/?id=21991c490810a4acf2e38cec99614bbd